# Gmail Chrome Extension "Refused to load script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Manifest v3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I've gone down the StackOverflow rabbit hole and similar questions I found either don't work or seem unsafe, so here's one more.

### My goal

I want to create a Google Chrome extension that works with Gmail. When someone composes a new email, it adds a little checkbox to the email builder. When someone checks this box, I just want to console log "checked".
[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNIc5.png)

### Methodology and problem

The easiest way to do this is just to create an attribute for "onchange" and call a function. Like this:

```
mauticCheckbox.setAttribute('onchange', 'test()')
```

But this runs into an error: "Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'report-sample' 'nonce-isArkHmhi5JlS1U0S0z2uA' 'unsafe-inline' 'strict-dynamic' https: http: 'unsafe-eval'"."

I read on other similar questions that you can disable the 'unsafe-inline', but that it's less secure. This might can be a last resort but I'd rather not do this.

So I keep researching and the other way to do this seems to be to add the JavaScript in the head tag. I don't have an HTML file for my code since I'm adding to the Gmail compose window, so my code was something like this:

```
window.onload=function() {
    addJavaScriptHead()
}

function addJavaScriptHead() {
    let head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'module';
    script.onload = function() {
        listenForClick(); // My function from background.js
    }
    script.src = 'background.js';
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

But alas, this runs into a similar (yet different) error message: "Refused to load the script 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/background.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'"."

How can I call a function when this element is changed from not clicked to clicked and vice versa?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If the file `background.js` belongs to your extension, use `script.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('background.js');`. Also add `background.js` to the `web_accessible_resources` entry of the manifest file.

Comment: All you need is `yourElement.onclick = () => { /* code */ }` in the content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried this initially. Since the checkbox only shows up once someone is composing an email, I get a "TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')
" on page load. Basically, JS checks for the element before it exists. I tried holding this off with a promise, but thought it simpler to just fire a function when the checkbox changed. Please let me know if I'm missing something though, I'm no expert :)

Comment: You can set window.onclick and check if event.target is your element.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to set your file in `web_accessible_resources` in manifest.json

```
"web_accessible_resources" : { 
   "resources": ["path/to/background.js"],
   "matches": ["<all_urls"]
}
```

Then, change the script src to:

```
script.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("path/to/background.js")
```